Blender camera shaking issue in cycles only
so i'm currently working on a short personal project on blender 4.1 and i got issue with the camera, keep in mind that this issue is only happening in cycles and cycles only, So in my project i got a simple low poly car with active rigid body on it and a baked rigid body animation cache for it. Now i simply had to animate a camera to record the car's path.
But when I try to do it the car shakes aggressively in the camera view( again it doesn't do that in evee render) but I want cycles for more accurate lighting for my project so cant switch with evee :(
I've attached a copy of my blender file and a possible clip to showcase the issue,
pLS PLS COULD someone help me with this issue as I've been working hard for this project and dont want it to stop bcoz of this.
P.s- I also tried making the camera follow a simple path curve and hoping the shaking would go but it didnt work.
Camera issue clip

There is no issue.
Cycles is just slower than EEVEE.
Cycles is not meant to be a real time renderer for the viewport.
When you render your simulation into a video there will be no stuttering as in your screen capture. The stuttering only occurs because cycles can not keep up with your real time simulation playback.
If you want to reduce the playback issues turn down your viewport render settings. (turn off Open Shading Language, turn off viewport denoising, turn down samples, etc...)

I did a 100 frame test render using Cycles and there is no stuttering.
https://youtu.be/_vDfmf4z3X0
Final render does not mean recording your screen right?
